# redireccionar pantalla acorde a la resolución

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando hacer un script que me redireccione a otro archivo html dependiendo de la resolución de pantalla mi código

```
<script>
var
pagina1 = "pagina1.html";
pagina2 = "pagina2.html";
pagina3 = "pagina3.html";
if (screen.widht < 1024){
location.href = pagina1;
}if (screen.width => 1024 && screen.width <= 1600) {
location.href = pagina2;
}if (screen.width > 1600) {
    location.href = pagina3;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos puedes realizar algo como esto:

```js
if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
    alert('Pantalla con resolucion menor a 960');
    //window.location = "index1.html";
}


if (window.innerWidth >= 960) {
    alert('Pantalla con resolucion mayor a 960');
    //window.location = "index2.html";
}
```

Para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar la siguiente documentación [innerWidth](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp)